# Python Conjecture

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

recently I have been trying to make a spin-off of Collatz conjecture using python 3.0. The program works as it should with positive integers, but it will not work with negative integers. In the program I check if the number is negative and if so I square it, and then proceed with collatz, rules. Unfortuanitly it gives off no error messages. Code below:

```
 import sys

 while True:
    number = input("Enter any positive integer: ")
    count = 0
    negative = "-"
    try:
        int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input...")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
       number = int(number)
        ORIGINAL = number
    while not number != 1:
        count += 1
        number ** 2
        if number % 2:
            number = 3*number+1
        elif not number % 2:
            number = number // 2
        print(number)
    while number != 1:
        count += 1
        if number % 2:
            number = 3*number+1
        elif not number % 2:
            number = number // 2
        print(number)

    print("The number "+str(ORIGINAL)+" took "+str(count)+" calculations to reach 1")
```

feel free to try out my code, it only uses python 3 and sys!

-thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to give a more detailed problem description than "it will not work". What did you expect to happen, and what actually happens? Also, none of this code checks for negativity, and whatever you were trying to do with `while not number != 1:`, you did it wrong.

Comment: ok help me with the "while not number != 1:"

Comment: also the result if I type -1 is -2,-1,-2,-1 infinitly. it doesnt squar the negative.

Comment: What's the `while not number != 1:` loop supposed to do? `while number == 1: number+= 1`? Why make a loop if it'll only do 1 iteration? Also, you're never checking if the number is negative, so I don't know why you'd expect negative numbers to be squared.

Comment: `if cond: - elif not cond:` can and should be written as `if cond: - else:`.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to do `elif not number % 2`. If an integer isn't odd it must be even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mapping used by the Collatz conjecture, a positive value always maps to another positive value. So you only need to check for negative values as part of your initialisation:

```
number = input("Enter any integer: ")
count = 0
try:
    number = int(number)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input...")
    sys.exit(0)
if number < 0:
    number = number ** 2
```

The loop `while not number != 1:` can be deleted. It will only run if number is equal to 1 (there is a double negative). If you enter 1, this loop will run once, assign 3*1+1 to number, and then the second loop will start. In other words, this loop is pointless: delete it.  Note the line `number ** 2` will not change the value of number, since there is no assignment.